# How to fetch json data without the json array name in android from django rest api ?

Tags: android, json, django

```
private void jsonParse() {

String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/products/";

JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject o = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        int id = o.getInt("id");
                        String title = o.getString("title");

                        String description = o.getString("description");
                        String price = o.getString("price");
                        mTextViewResult.append(title + ", " + String.valueOf(id) + ", "+price +"," + description + "\n\n");
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
});

mQueue.add(request);}
```

This is my android code

```
 [  {
"id": 1,
"title": "t-shirt",
"description": "this is a good t-shirt",
"price": "39.99"
```

},

```
{
"id": 2,
"title": "Jeans",
"description": "this is a jean",
"price": "89.99"}]
```

This is my json data

How can i fetch the json data which don't have a json array name.
In my android i need to have json array name to parse the json data.But my django rest api produce json data without json array name.

Answer (score 0):

The response is a list of jsons. You need a [JSONArrayRequest](https://afzaln.com/volley/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonArrayRequest.html) object to get the `JSONArray`.

**Example**:

```
String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/products/";

JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            try {
                // `response` is the JSONArray that you need to iterate
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject o = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    int id = o.getInt("id");
                    String title = o.getString("title");

                    String description = o.getString("description");
                    String price = o.getString("price");
                    mTextViewResult.append(title + ", " + String.valueOf(id) + ", "+price +"," + description + "\n\n");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
      @Override
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
      }
});
```

Comment: [   JSONObject o = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); ]What should i write in this part?

Comment: But it can't fetch the json data and show in android. When i click the button it doesn't show anything.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but i'm new to android that's why i can't get it. This is logcat showing-\ 03-26 14:54:09.785 2532-2636/com.example.android.ecom D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
03-26 14:54:09.963 2532-2636/com.example.android.ecom E/EGL_emulation: tid 2636: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
03-26 14:54:09.963 2532-2636/com.example.android.ecom W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x99843280, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH

Comment: Sorry to bother you but i'm new to android that's why i can't get it. This is logcat showing-
03-26 14:54:09.785 2532-2636/com.example.android.ecom D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
03-26 14:54:09.963 2532-2636/com.example.android.ecom E/EGL_emulation: tid 2636: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
03-26 14:54:09.963 2532-2636/com.example.android.ecom W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x99843280, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH